# Tkinter radio button not working correctly (always stores choice as first item)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I am using python 3 with Tkinter, when I select an item from the radio button, it correctly shows the radio button and all the contents of the list, however when I use the .get() function it only returns the first radio button item each time. I cannot seem to find why this isn't working correctly and this code was working perfectly earlier tonight. For contact the list stockList is ['apple','google','Tesla','amazon'] and this all displays in the correct order however the function stockStore only prints apple each time.

```
    stockList = ReadFile.PullStockCsv(self)
    var = tk.StringVar()
    var.set(stockList[0])

    for item in stockList:
        button = tk.Radiobutton(self, text=item, variable=var, value=item)
        button.pack()

    btnPlotGraph = tk.Button(self, text="Plot Graph", command=lambda: stockStore(self, var))
    btnPlotGraph.pack()

    button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
    button3.pack()

    def stockStore(self, var):
        y = var.get()
        print(y)
        ReadFile.textWrite(self, y)
        controller.show_frame(GraphPlot)
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify it as you didn't post a verifiable example. But this code returns whichever radio button is selected.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
stockList =  ['apple','google','Tesla','amazon']
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(stockList[0])

for item in stockList:
    button = tk.Radiobutton(text=item, variable=var, value=item)
    button.pack()

btnPlotGraph = tk.Button(text="Plot Graph", command=lambda: stockStore(var))
btnPlotGraph.pack()

button3 = tk.Button(text="Back to Home")
button3.pack()


def stockStore(var):
    y = var.get()
    print(y)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not working for me. Even selection is not getting printed through print(y) in definition.